# How to connect an IBOutlet to the storyboard from a class category

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, objective-c-category

I have a CarViewController class which has several class category files. `CarViewController.m` imports `CarViewController+protected.h`. I want to have some IBOutlet properties inside `car+protected.h` so that I can use these in both my `CarViewController.m` and other class category implementation files.

I opened up the assistant editor and was not able to drag from my view to the Outlet in `CarViewController+protected.h`. However, I was able to drag from the Outlets in `CarViewController+protected.h` to the view in the storyboard.

I ran my code an eventually got an `this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key` error, which usually means that you have an outdated connection somewhere in the project. I have checked for this and cleaned the project but I cannot seem to get past this error.

Is it possible to have IBOutlets connect to a storyboard in a class category header file? If not, can I use a class extension file? My CarViewController class is becoming very large and I want to use categories or extensions to break down the file size and better organize my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not declare properties in a category, so it's impossible to connect an IBOutlet property to a category.

In your case, making `CarViewController` a super class and making subclasses inheriting from the class can solve the problem.